# How to set boolean variable to true in mongodb using function in service in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular6

I have created a function in service using nodejs to set the boolean variable to true upon button click. But its not working.

I'm using get method in service to do the above. 
// in html

```
<tr *ngFor="let status of bookstatus">
              <td>{{status.bookname}}</td>
              <td>{{status.issuedate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
              <td>{{status.returndate}}</td>
              <td>{{status.membername}}</td>
              <td>{{status.fine}}</td>
              <td>{{status.status}}</td>
              <td><button type="button" (click)="returnbook(status._id)">BookReturn</button></td>
              </tr>
```

// in ts

```
returnbook(id: number) {
   this.bookissueservice.returnbook(id).subscribe(response => {window.alert('book returned'); });

   if (this.bookstatus.isreturned === true) {
  this.bookstatus.status = 'returned';
  var date1 = new Date(this.bookreturn);
  var date2 = new Date(this.bookstatus.returndate);
  var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
  var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
  if (diffDays !== 0) {
    const res = 50;
    this.fine = res + diffDays;
  }
  else {this.fine = 0; }
}
 }
```

//in service

```
returnbook(id:number){
  return this.http.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/memberdetails/${id}`).
    pipe(map(response=>response));
}
```

//in api

```
router.get('/return/:id?',(req,res)=>{
                var body=req.params.id;
                var id=body.id;
                bookissue.findById(id,(error,bookissue)=>{if(error){
                    console.log(error);}  
              /*bookissue.isreturned is the boolean variable which I'm trying to set to true on button click */
                bookissue.isreturned = 1;
                bookissue.save(function(error,returned){
                    if(error){
                        console.log(error);
                        return next(error);
                    }
                    res.json({status:true,message:'saved',data:returned});

                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: there's no error but the boolean vairable  'isreturned' doesnot set to 1 or true on button click. Could you suggest a method to set the boolean variable to 1?

Comment: is book issue returned for the id or is it null or something? Please also post the returned `returned`.

Comment: your router is `get`, should probably be `post` if you're expecting data from client

Comment: `var body=req.params.id; var id=body.id;`. I think you're incorrectly assigning to id and it would be an undefined value. I think it should be `var id=req.params.id;` instead of above and it should work.

Comment: Not getting data from client...when corresponding user clicks the button the status of bookstatus should change to not returned to returned. Im doing the work of library bookissue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna save the boolean variable to "1" use the update query.

```
bookissue.update({_id:id},{$set:{isreturned:true}},(error,result)=>{
if(error){
      console.log(error);
      return next(error);
 }
 console.log("result : ",result);
 res.json({status:true,message:'saved',data:result});
 });
```

Comment: The OP is using mongoose then he should use `save` to make update so that data adheres to its schema and validations are performed.

Comment: Yes, But I guess data will not change as he is trying to change the boolean to number. And when we fetch and save mongo object want to retain it's property.

Comment: please console your id too, and try to see when you fetch the data using find. Are you getting the mongo document or not ?

Comment: sry didn't get u @Pankaj Jiondal

Comment: I am saying may be the id you are providing in the query is not correct, so to be sure that the id is correct. please console it and also call the query findOne using the query {_id:id} so we will be sure that we are providing the correct data.
And are you using mongoose ?

Comment: Ok...Yes using mongoose @Pankaj

Comment: mongoose will not allow you to save "1". if you have mentioned  

isreturned : {type: Boolean} in the mongoose schema definition. it will convert it to true.

Comment: yes i changed the isreturned to set to true; bookissue.findOne({_id:id},{$set:{isreturned:true}},(error,returned)=>{
                    console.log(id);
                    if(error){
                          console.log(error);
                   
                     }
                     res.json({status:true,message:'saved',data:returned});
                     });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190950/discussion-between-sethu-and-pankaj-jindal).